# Cannot erase micro SD card

Tags: disk-utility, partition, sd-card

Two volumes mount when it's in:

[image]

[image]

so it looks like I partitioned it when I tried to install something on it but "Partition" cannot be clicked.

[image]

"Erase" fails on both partitions:

[image]

I tried the SD app called "SD Card Formatter" but this also didn't work.

[image]

**Can I wipe this Micro SD card clean, and is there a way to test it to see if it's usable (I have a lot of issues with it)?**

Comment: It's probably dead. Bin it. There is a long, detailed explanation on Super User - http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only - but the short version is, it's probably firmware locked after a write error. This is, to all intents & purposes, irreversible. There's one outside chance - hit Cmd/2 which will show the devices rather than just the partitions & try to Erase the whole card.

Comment: In disk utility, if you clic on View icon and select Display all disk, then select the SD card and “Erase" is it better?

Comment: What Tetsujin said is the actual situation. Displaying the Volume and trying to erase it just resulted in "Erase Process has Failed (...) Couldn't Open Device". $30 dollars that I can safely place in the poubelle.

Comment: Note that in some cases the partition is locked by some process on the device it is meant to be used on. So if this came out of a camera of some sort you could try and format it *in the camera.* failing that scenario, yeah bin it.

Comment: @SteveChambers - it's part FAT & part ExtFS3 - more likely a failed nix installer than anything from a camera.

Comment: @Tetsujin it's an OS for a gaming handheld that didn't bake properly, that's how it became corrupted (baked with Apple Pi Baker). See my answer after Steve gave me an idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was ready to follow the suggestions in the comments and put the **SD Card** in the .

However, Steve's comment brought up the idea that a *camera* might be able to format the card that the computer couldn't (even though the card's firmware lock was not a result of using it in a camera).

I tried putting the Micro SD in my **Panasonic LX7** but got an error message right away ("please reinsert the memory card"). Then I placed the card in my **Sony Nex 5** and the Sony was able to Format the card without a problem.

[image]

When I placed the card back into the Mac, it was repaired.

This solved my problem, but I am grateful for the comments that led me in the right direction.

I understand that a solution involving a mirrorless camera might not be accessible to everyone, but I would recommend to **not** trash SD cards that become locked after write errors, and to try formatting it in various devices that have a Format function.